# Returning multiple elements for apply method

Tags: scala, chisel

I am working with a DSL (Chisel) in which one particular part of the library requires me to define a `Seq` of items. I have several companion objects to create some intermediate logic and return one of these items. I have a situation where I want to actually return two of these items, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

Let's say the "items" here are `Person`. (What `Person` is here is not important)

The DSL wants you to describe all your `Person`s through a `Seq`.

```scala
val p1 = new Person(1)
val p2 = new Person(2)

Seq(p1,p2)
```

I have a case where I want to link two people together. For example, I know some people have friends that they drag everywhere, so if they are showing up so is their friend (even if I don't like them). So I want to be able to do something similar to the following.

```scala
object Group {
  def apply(): Person, Person = {  //return two of these
    val pA  = new Person(10)
    val pAA = new Person(10+1)
  }
}
```

this way, I can easily just do the following

```scala
Seq(p1, p2, Group)

//The Seq should have p1, p2, and the pA, pAA
```

Since this is a DSL, I do not have access to change the internals. I *could* create each piece of the Seq, then combine them all together, however this isn't ideal as this is something I'll do often enough that a good solution is desirable. I can't send back a tuple for the same reason.

I tried to see if the variable args would work on the return, but that did not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

Update for our lord and savior Jack Koenig

This is utilizing the RocketChip `RegisterRotuer` node to describe the `RegFields`

It is often in my designs where I have a signal coming from some logic and I want software to have the ability to block the upstream logic and drive a signal manually (think about some enable you want software to be able to drive). To do this I build a SW register that represents the driven value, and a "mux" SW register that handles the control. What I've currently done is this (currently returning a `Seq[RegField]` but hopefully you see where I wanted this to be two `RegField` types

```scala
/**
  *   Creates a muxed override register. This allows software to take control of a particular signal by setting the "_mux" register
  *   high. Once in this mode, the value of the signal is based on the software register defined here.
  *
  *   This method makes the assumption that you want the two bitfields to be next to each other (reg then mux). If you do not want this
  *   or can't do this (because the signal you want to control is >=32bits) you will have to create two separate RWReg. One for the mux
  *   and one for the SW control value
  *
  *
  *   val rx_reset_reg    = Wire(Bool())
  *   val rx_reset_mux    = Wire(Bool())
  *   val rx_reset        = WavClockMux (rx_reset_mux,  rx_reset_reg,   io.core.rx_reset)
  *   WavD2DRxRegs.CoreOverride   -> Seq(WavRWReg(rx_reset_reg,0.U,      "rx_reset",       "RX Reset"),
  *                                      WavRWReg(rx_reset_mux,0.U,      "rx_reset_mux",   "Mux override for rx_reset")),
  *
  *
  *   This method also has the nuance that it returns a Seq[RegField]. So you must concatenate this companion object with the higher leve
  *   Seq[RegField] that we normally use for register generation
  *   
  *   WavRWMuxReg(in=io.core.tx_en,     muxed=io.ana.tx_en,    reg_reset=false.B, mux_reset=false.B, "tx_en",    "Main TX enable") ++ Seq(<other regFields>)
  */
object WavRWMuxReg{
  
  def apply[T <: Data](in: T, muxed : T, reg_reset: T, mux_reset: Bool, name: String, desc: String)(implicit p: Parameters): Seq[RegField] = {
    //val reg = RegInit(reset)
    val reg = RegInit(muxed.cloneType, reg_reset)
    reg.suggestName("swi_" + name)
    
    val mux = RegInit(mux_reset)
    mux.suggestName("swi_" + name + "_mux")
    
    muxed := Mux(mux, reg, in)
    
    //litValue returns the Bigint value
    val rf_reg = RegField(reg.getWidth, reg.asUInt, RegFieldDesc(name,        desc, access=RegFieldAccessType.RW , reset=Some(reg_reset.litValue)))
    val rf_mux = RegField(1           , mux.asUInt, RegFieldDesc(name+"_mux", "Mux control for corresponding register", access=RegFieldAccessType.RW , reset=Some(mux_reset.litValue)))
    Seq(rf_reg, rf_mux)
  }
}
```

- `in` is the input logic
- `muxed` will be the post muxed signal (can be assigned to something like a `Bundle` signal)
- `*_reset` are the reset value for the auto generated value/mux SW registers

So ideally I would use this to create both and would be able to just say

```scala
node.regmap(
  0x0 -> Seq(WavRWReg(/*custom method that returns RegField*/),
             WavRWMuxReg(/*returns two RegFields*/))
)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example using the actual Chisel APIs? This sounds to me a bit like the "HardwareTuple" idea (see https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/issues/864). While that issue is a bit old, I have an idea (`DataView`) that I'm hoping to implement in Chisel 3.5 that may do what you want (https://gist.github.com/jackkoenig/20bffc2e9270386044aba9f00bc82fd5).

Comment: Hey @JackKoenig, I've updated with the Chisel/RocketChip specifics. It seems like more of a Scala limitation. The workaround proposed by Dima isn't bad, it's just a little funky and looks a little ugly when you have to do several of them. I don't think it's worth expanding Chisel/RC to compensate for this. But happy to hear your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Hey there Steveo, yeah I think Dima's solution is best here. You could also use the `Seq` and do a `.flatten` if that looks better for you, but unless rocket-chip were to supply a `RegFields(...)` sort of construct, you're sort of stuck with the slightly ugly stuff.

Comment: Cool, I will stick with Dima's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a `Seq` and concatenate?

```
    object PlusN {
       def apply(m, n): Seq[Person] = (m to m+n).map(Person)
    }
    
   val people = Seq(p1, p2) ++ PlusN(10, 1)
```

Comment: This may be the solution I have to use. I wanted to stay away from this if possible to clean up the DSL interfacing.